# Make the email field required based on the dropdown list value selection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

My application is in mvc 3

I have a ddlfor in my view which lists two values A and B.
There is one more field email in same view
I need to make this email field a required or mandatory filed only if the selected value of the ddl is 'A'.And no need to validate if the value selected is 'B'.
How can i implement this scenario.PLsss help me

Now in my model, email is a mandatory field. Do i need to change that?
If i change that where i will make email mandatory and not mandatory based on ddl value?

Pls advice me.
Thanks in advance,
Priya

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in JQuery. In Jquery check the value of drop down if 'A' and email field is empty return false so that form will not be submitted.

On server side rather than using data annotation you can have a custom method to validate.

Answer (score 0):

`IValidatableObject` interface allows you to perform validation at model level :

```
public class MyModel : IValidatableObject
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string SelectedValue { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (SelectedValue == "A" && string.IsNullOrEmpty(Email))
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Email address is required.", new [] { "Email" });
        }
    }
}
```

It will highlight Email field if your selected value in the dropdownlist is "A".

Comment: But how can i call this in the selected index change?

Comment: This is intended to work on server side, when you submit your form. If you need to add a warning message when selection is changed, on client side, you'll probably need to do that in jQuery, like : `$("#myDropDownList").change(function() { /* test if mandatory then display warning message */ });`

Comment: Thanks Reda, in client side i implementd the appearance of warning images based on the the ddl values using jquery as u said.But can you please tell me in detail if u dont mind how this can be achieved in server side, how can i write custom vlaidation classes in model?, then how can i call that class, how can i pass the ddl selected value to that class and how can i return the val;idation result based on the selected value..pls help me

Comment: The code in my answer already does the job. You just need to have a parameter of type `MyModel` (or whatever you named it) in your post action, and a process called the `Model Binding` will perform validation for you (as well as instantiating you model type parameter with property values coming from fields in you form). It uses attributes defined for your properties, and also the Validate function. If any error is detected, the `ModelState` property in your controller will have an `IsValid` property returning false.

Comment: You know then that data submitted is incorrect, and you can just do a `Return View()` to display your form again for further corrections. I'm sorry if it seems unclear, but you're asking for some basic yet big concepts about ASP.NET MVC, maybe you should check more articles about `Model Binding`, `ModelState`, `ValidationAttribute` and such.