# Custom Range validator on mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, range, customvalidator

i would like to do a custom Range Validator but i'm not sure how to proceed in this.
I need the Range validator to be active only if a boolean stay false, if the bool is true, the validation should not apply. Something like the RequiredIfFalse of foolproof validation.

```
[RequiredIfFalse("UnEquip", ErrorMessage = "Le champ 'Nombre de salariés' doit être     renseigné")]
    [Range(1, 1000000, ErrorMessage = "Le nombre de salariés doit être compris entre 1 et 1000000")]
    public int Salaries { get; set; }
```

something like this, but combining those 2 type of validation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your boolean value from another property or a constant defined with your custom RangeAttribute ?

Comment: the boolean is in the model, it's a checkbox on the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform this validation at model level, because it implies several properties at once. Check this link, for a similar issue : [Make the email field required based on the dropdown list value selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19565855/make-the-email-field-required-based-on-the-dropdown-list-value-selection/19568423#19568423)

In your case, `Validate` will test your boolean and `Salaries` value, if `false` and `Salaries > 1000000` or `Salaries < 1`, you'll return a new `ValidationResult` containing your error message.

Comment: thanks, it works almost likea charm. but i have a little issue when the validation message should pop. It only pop if i have no other validation error on the field without the custom validation. I am using a validation summary, with JQuery.validation.js do i have to add some modification on the validation.js so that all the error message show at the same time ?

Comment: I suspect that your other validation errors are triggered client side. Unfortunately, validation at model level only works server side. It may change in the future, but for now it is how it works :/

Comment: So i should disable client side validation, or find another way to validate ? I should search how to turn off client side validation and test this

Comment: even if the client side validation is turned off, the problem is still here.

Comment: Can you show us how you define your other validation rules on your model ?

Comment: just like this : 
   `[Required(ErrorMessage = "Le champ 'fonction' doit être renseigné")]
  public string Fonction { get; set; }`


for the scripts i use : 
   `jquery.validate.js`
   `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`

Comment: Have you tried removing those script references ? I'm not sure that client side validation is indeed disabled. Also, you can try this : `@{ Html.EnableClientValidation(false); }` at the beginning of your form.

Comment: well, i have something new, i have created other method to make custom validation for other props. but now i have an error on compilation saying that FormModel does not implement IValidatableObject. i tries deleting the new methods, but now, even the forst one (that was working at least 10 times) put up the same error. I don't have any error when i delete IValidatableObject but of course the custom validation don't work... i hope this is not a problem between the interface developed by my collegue...

Comment: Check this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject.validate(v=vs.110).aspx . When you inherit from `IValidatableObject`, you must implement the `Validate` method (where you perform your validation tests), with the signature specified in this link. Otherwise it won't compile.

Comment: i'll look at this, thanks
so, i can't us this method on several prop with different range condition on my model ?

Comment: ok, never mind my last question, i've solved it by myself by testing.
disabling client validation still not solved the message problem though, it's probably a problem on the js